# kernel of this map via Groebner basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

There is a map $\phi$ from a polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_2 [x,y,z]$ to $\mathbb{F}_4[t]$ where $\mathbb{F}_4=\{0,1,\omega,\omega^2\}$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ with characteristic $2$. The map which is a ring homomorphism, is defined as follows $\phi: \mathbb{F}_2 [x,y,z] \rightarrow  \mathbb{F}_4[t]$ such that $\phi:x\rightarrow 1+t, y\rightarrow 1+\omega t, z\rightarrow 1+\omega^2 t$. The Kernel of this map can be found by finding the Groebner basis for the ideal $K=<x-1-t,y-1-\omega t,z-1-\omega^2 t>$ and taking it's intersection with $\mathbb{F}_2 [x,y,z]$. (from Introduction to Groebner Basis by Adams and Loustaunau). Using this method, I get Kernel as $\{1- \omega+\omega y-z, 1-\omega+\omega x-y,x-2y+y^2+z-xz\}$ but the correct answer to the kernel is $\{1+x+y+z,1+xy+yz+zx\}$. What is the wrong step? Also, I calculated the Groebner basis for the ideal $K$ in Mathematica using DegreeRevLex monomial ordering with $t>x>y>z$.

Comment: There should be no $\omega$s in the kernel; $\phi$ is defined on $\mathbb{F}_2\left[x,y,z\right]$, not on $\mathbb{F}_4\left[x,y,z\right]$. Probably the $\omega$ somehow slipped into your base ring when you were computing the ideal $K$.

Comment: actually, one problem that I ignored is that the method in the book is for a map from polynomial ring defined over the field K to polynomial ring defined over the same field K. In this problem, the field in the image is the extension of the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ and not the same.

Comment: Yes, which is why you should treat $\mathbb{F}_4$ as $\mathbb{F}_2\left[t\right]/\left(t^2-t-1\right)$. The variable $t$ goes into your polynomial ring.

Comment: Do you mean I should redefine the action of map $\phi$ on the variables $x,y,z$ as in the statement, the map is defined in terms of $\omega$ which is an element of representation of $\mathbb{F}_4=\{0,1,\omega,\omega^2\}$?

Comment: No, you should treat the codomain of the map as $\mathbb{F}_2\left[t,u\right]/\left(u^2-u-1\right)$. (The $t$ in my previous comment has become a $u$ here, since $t$ already stands for another variable.)